# asp.net required field not fired for textbox

Tags: jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer, validation

I use a `requiredfieldvalidator` for some textbox and each textbox has placeholder attribute and but when I click submit button the validators did not fire and this problem is in IE because IE not support placeholder by default so I use Jquery for this purpose and this is my code:
Jquery:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function () {
           // $("#txtAddress").removeAttr("style");
           var userAgent = navigator.userAgent.toString().toLowerCase();
           if (userAgent.indexOf('ie') != -1) {
               $('[placeholder]').focus(function () {
                   var input = $(this);
                   if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
                       input.val('');
                       input.removeClass('placeholder');
                   }
               }).blur(function () {
                   var input = $(this);
                   if (input.val() == '' || input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
                       input.addClass('placeholder');

                       input.val(input.attr('placeholder'));
                   }
               }).blur();
           }
       });
</script>
```

Asp:

```
  <asp:Label ID="lblResult"  runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
         <p>
           <asp:TextBox ID="txtOrgName" runat="server" placeholder="ناوی دامەزراوە"></asp:TextBox> 
           <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ForeColor="red" CssClass="validator" ControlToValidate="txtOrgName" ErrorMessage="*"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
       </p>   
        <br/>
       <p>
           <asp:TextBox ID="txtPhone" runat="server" placeholder="تەلەفۆن"></asp:TextBox> 

           <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" CssClass="validator" ControlToValidate="txtPhone" ForeColor="red" ErrorMessage="*"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
       </p>
       <br/>
       <p>
           <asp:TextBox ID="txtMobile" runat="server" placeholder="مۆبایل"></asp:TextBox>

           <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtMobile" CssClass="validator" ForeColor="red" ErrorMessage="*"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
       </p>
       <br/>
       <p>      
           <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddress" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="120px" Width="200px" style="direction: ltr;" placeholder="ناونیشان">

           </asp:TextBox>
           <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtAddress" CssClass="validator" ForeColor="red" ErrorMessage="*"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
       </p>
        <p>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="تۆمارکردن" />
        </p>
```

Comment: Try using CausesValidation="True" for textbox

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        if ($.browser.msie === true) {
            $('#formId').find('[placeholder]').focus(function () {
                var inputObjObj = $(this);
                if (inputObj.val() == inputObj.attr('placeholder')) {
                    inputObj.val('').removeClass('placeholder');
                }
            }).blur(function () {
                var inputObj = $(this);
                if (inputObj.val() == '' || inputObj.val() == inputObj.attr('placeholder')) {
                    inputObj.addClass('placeholder').val(inputObj.attr('placeholder'));
                }
            }).blur();

            $('#formId').find('#Button1').click(function () {
                $(this).parents('form').find('[placeholder]').each(function (i) {
                    var inputObj = $(this);
                    if (inputObj.val() == inputObj.attr('placeholder')) {
                        inputObj.val('').removeClass('placeholder');
                    }
                });

                if (Page_ClientValidate()) {
                    //Form is valid;
                } else {
                    //Form is not valid;

                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
    });
```